# Swift Character Count

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to xcode, need to find the character count of the String in the UILabel

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            curr_channel.text = ""
            let tag = (sender as! UIButton).tag
            if((curr_channel.text?.character.count())! < 2){
                 curr_channel.text = curr_channel.text! + String(tag)
            }
        }
```

Comment: According to your code the *count* is 0 as the `text` property is set to an empty string.

Comment: Yeah, the if statement is giving an error "Editor placeholder in source file". I need two characters in my UILabel.  if((curr_channel.text?.count)! < 2){
             curr_channel.text = curr_channel.text! + String(tag)
        }

Comment: Again the code makes no sense. The *count* of an empty string is always zero.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you need :

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let tag = (sender as! UIButton).tag
    if let text = curr_channel.text, text.count < 2 {
        curr_channel.text = "\(text) \(tag)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can print/ get the character count in a UILable.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
  let countOfCharsInLabel = myLabel.text?.count
  print("\(countOfCharsInLabel)")
}
```